# Struggling with making my app displaying properly on iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad

I have a little trouble grasping the concept of making views that will display proper on iPhone, iPhone 3G(s), iPhone 4 and iPad.

Lets say I have regular UIImageButton at a position of (200, 300), and size is (100, 60).
If I define those values in CGRect structure the button will scale properly on iPhone depending on whether or not it is with iPhone (320px, 480px) or iPhone 4 (640px, 960px). I only need to provide a extra set of images with the doubled size since I am not specifying real pixels but points.

However on iPad this does not work, or else I am doing something wrong because it does not display properly.

I want to know if there is possible to specify that the imagebutton in this example would stay at the same location as on iPhone. I also need to know how I should "properly" initialize a e.g. UIImageButton. Is it correct to say

> [[UIImageButton alloc]
>   initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200.0f,
>   300.0f, 100.0f, 60.0f)];

if I want to have it located on the same location on the iPad version. Could anyone explain? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easier to do this in Interface Builder.  Select the view, and in the Inspector click on the tab with the ruler (third tab in).  The "Autosizing" section lets you control how the location and size of the view changes depending on the device and orientation.

To do this in code, you change the `autoresizingMask` property of the UIView, e.g.

```
view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight
```

Comment: I need to do this in code since I have many views, so I want to be able to do this in one of my BaseController. I tried the codesnippet and it worked. Thank you! However I have one more question, is it correct to to specify positions/sizes in relation to a iPhone(320px, 480px)? And then setting the autoresizemask?